# Twilio Voice, How to show the incoming call and connect to the call in flutter

Tags: flutter, twilio

I am implementing the twilio voice sdk using the [twilio_voice](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_voice) package for this purpose. I have successfully implementing the outgoing call using step by step guide lines from the [twilio_voice](https://github.com/diegogarciar/twilio_voice), I have hosted the function to generate the accessToken on cloud firebase and when I make a call its successfully hit the twilio voice sdk and a call produced and a log event recorded on twilio account. on the other device I receive a firebase event remote message with json response in following format

`{twi_message_id: RUa6a23c3599c3bd41ddcd56d841758ded, twi_to: client:ZwgvauuqUzcyQI0wXBm9lzgUjJa2, twi_from: 9948288789297409926959485522, twi_account_sid: ACCOUNT SID, twi_call_sid: CAebffd58808812e7bf6e2f1e71b315989, twi_answer_timeout: 600, twi_message_type: twilio.voice.call, twi_bridge_token: TOKEN VALUE HERE`

I can show the call notification using local notification package but my question is how to connect with the incoming call?

I am using `TwilioVoice.instance.call.answer();` but null exception throw on it. I am trying since 1 week but got no solution. anybody already implemented this? please correct my direction.

Comment: Hi, can you share the code with me? I am not able to even make calls.
I cloned the repo directly. I have received calls successfully on the web but Android is not working